# Tab Tamer settings

Tags: 7, users, routes

Is there way to show tabs not only for admin?

I need tabs on user account page for authorized users. In user permissions I didn't found this option..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your own tabs, check out `vertical_tabs_example` module in [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples).